# Python - writing console output to disk

Tags: python, command-line

Is there a way to write the console output to disk?  In other words, as the system writes to the console, it also writes to a text file?

I am hoping that there is a simple setting in blender rather than having to write a bunch of scripts to write messages to a file on my disk drive.

This is so I can figure out why my script is causing blender to shut down.

Comment: Start Blender with `blender.exe > myfile.log`

Comment: @rob Sounds great, would you like to add this as an answer?

Comment: If you simply want to review the output, you can start Blender from the shell/cmd. Simply opening it as `>blender` will write its output to that window, which doesn't close even if Blender crashes.

Comment: Thanks - I have no idea what ```blender.exe>myfile.log``` means, nor 'simply opening it as ```>blender```'

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the **Blender** executable from the command line.

In **Windows** this requires you to run a new **Command Prompt** and the execute *blender.exe* from the correct location.
In Linux/MAC the process is similar.

On my **Windows** machine, I go to the **Start Bar** and type in *Command* 
[image]

in the new window I type the directory to where Blender was installed followed by the program I want to run, *blender.exe*

To capture all the output a redirection character **>** is used.

Finally I have a folder on my C: drive called "**tmp**" that I know I have access to write to. You will have to enter a folder and filename **your Windows user** can write to.
[image]

After running Blender the new file *myfile.log* has the following contents. This was after simply opening and closing blender. (*type* is a windows program that just dumps text files to the console)

[image]